# Is にとって　often shortened to に　in spoken, colloquial Japanese?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

For example, 「昼ごはんに寄せ鍋を食べた」or 「私に(は)辛すぎる」, in both cases meaning "for".

Comment: Are you saying that in the first example you think that に might be short for にとって?